# Weird rqt_graph when running turtlesim

Tags: ros, rosnode, turtlesim, beginner-tutorials, rqt-graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going through the ROS tutorials and on the "[Understanding Topics](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics#Using_rqt_graph)" tutorial in section 1.2.1 when I launch `rqt_graph` I get this image:
[image: image description]

It should be this:

[image description http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=rqt_graph_turtle_key.png](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=rqt_graph_turtle_key.png)(according to the tutorial)

`my_turtle` was from the previous tutorial and I tried killing it with `rosnode kill /my_turtle` but when I restarted `rqt_graph` it didn't change. Any ideas as to why this is happening? Also why are there three turtlesim nodes besides the `my_turtle` node, instead of two?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214853/weird-rqt_graph-when-running-turtlesim/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

but your rosnode kill /my_turtle does not match your **_my_turtle** with underscore in the front.

---

Originally posted by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) with karma: 110 on 2015-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-07-29**:
when I try to kill node `_my_turtle` I get this message: `ERROR: Unknown node(s):

- /_my_turtle
  `Also when I run`rosnode list` I get the following:

  /my_turtle
  /rosout
  /rostopic_13088_1438192992473
  /rostopic_13492_1438193756802
  /teleop_turtle
  /turtlesim

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-07-29**:
I also just noticed that my mode was set to Nodes/Topic (active). If I switch to Nodes only it looks better but not the same

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-07-29**:
Yeah Luke I am not sure. But your graph does not have to look exactly like the tutorial. the circle inside the square of each node is fine.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-07-29**:
My suggestion is to run it again to see if you have any more issues.

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-07-29**:
It disappeared now. Thanks for the help!

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-07-29**:
no problem, you helped yourself lol